# Is it possible to display directory contents automatically while typing command?

Tags: command-line, files

I'm new to Linux. I wonder if it is possible to make terminal display directory contents automatically while I typing a command with directory arguments?

For example, if I want to do

```
cp ./fileA ~/folderA/folderB/folderC/fileA
```

Sometimes I can't memorise the destination directory correctly, as a result I need to use `ls` repeatedly to find the correct directory before finally using `cp` command, which is not convenient.

If I cannot remember what's in folderA beforehand, it'll be nice if the contents in folderA is automatically displayed while I typing:

```
cp ./fileA ~/folderA
```

Thanks!

Comment: TAB usually works...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual action in case you don't remember the name is to press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Most shells (including `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`) will guess as many characters as they could on the first keystroke, then display a list of matching files and directories on the second.

For example, if you have `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3` in your home directory, then typing `cp file ~/d` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice would produce

```
dir1    dir2    dir3
$cp file ~/dir
```

Here, your shell could guess from the letter "d" you have typed that you want one of the three directories mentioned above, and filled the common part ("dir") in your command for you. All you have to do is to type "1", "2" or "3", and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used multiple times while typing the same command. If your target directory is buried deep in the directory three, or if there are many files/directories to chose from, it is convenient to type a few characters, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, check how many the shell could guess, type a few more, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again etc. Thanks @EightBitTony for the remark.

Note that command line competition using <kbd>Tab</kbd> also works with command names. `cp` is short enough to type entirely, but if you need something longer like `wpa_supplicant` then typing `wpa_s` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will save you a fair amount of keystrokes. Personally, I use `zsh` which is by default configured to guess command line options, e.g. typing `service sshd r` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> is automatically expanded to `service sshd restart`.

Comment: ... and you can use completion more than once in the same command, so `cp fileA ~/f` then Tab then type `A/` to get `cp ./fileA ~/folderA/` then type `/f` and hit Tab again, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Tab key` double time to complete the file or folder name while typing.
That is feature of linux.

Comment: That's a shell feature.

Comment: Which is also dependant on shell options, and while it's usually turned on in modern shell deployments, there's no guarantee.